# Finding a Workaround for Submitting Form Data Inside an Isolate Scope

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a few forms nested within a tab element in my application. Here's the tab and pane directive code:

```
.directive('tabs', function() {
  return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope: {},
  controller: function($scope) {
    var panes = $scope.panes = [];
    $scope.select = function(pane) {
      angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
        pane.selected = false;
      });
      pane.selected = true;
    };
    this.addPane = function(pane) {
      if (panes.length === 0) {
        $scope.select(pane);
      }
      panes.push(pane);
    };
  },
  templateUrl: 'partials/tabs.ejs'
}

.directive('pane', function() {
  return {
    require: '^tabs',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      title: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
      tabsCtrl.addPane(scope);
    },
    templateUrl: 'partials/pane.ejs'
  };
});
```

Here's the controller code:

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'courses', function($scope, courses) {
  $scope.courses = courses.courses; 
  $scope.addCourse = function() {
    if (!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') return;
    courses.create({
      title: $scope.title,
      description: $scope.description,
      professor: $scope.professor
    });
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.description = '';
    $scope.professor = '';
  };
}])
```

Finally, here's the relevant HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
    <tabs class="container">
      <pane title="All Courses"
        <div class="container">
          <form ng-submit="addCourse()">
          ...
```

Upon form submission, the `addCourse()` function isn't called. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the isolate scope created from the tab directive, but I'm not sure how to work around this so that the form submission works.

Comment: how do you submit the form? you have a button element? is the button type=submit?

Comment: Yes it is through a button type=submit element. I ended up fixing the issue by changing to static tabs using bootstrap and jQuery instead of transcluded scopes in Angular, which fixed the problem.